# vnstat data question

Tags: vnstat

Test driving vnstat & trying match the usage with the provider report

vnstat tells me I've used "155.06 KiB"  -or- 0.00015878144 Gb last 30 days

Provider reports 972gb use last 30 days

Thoughts ?

---

Yes, one/only system connected to isp

Comment: Is the computer running vnstat the only one that uses data from your provider?

Comment: It could be you are having `vnstat` report WiFi traffic but most of your usage is on Ethernet. You can add have `vnstat` add the two together though: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/vnStat